# Pandas replace with default value

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a pandas dataframe I want to replace a certain column conditionally.

eg:

```
   col

 0 Mr
 1 Miss
 2 Mr
 3 Mrs
 4 Col.
```

I want to map them as

```
{'Mr': 0, 'Mrs': 1, 'Miss': 2}
```

If there are other titles now available in the dict then I want them to have a default value of `3`

The above example becomes

```
   col

 0 0
 1 2
 2 0
 3 1
 4 3
```

Can I do this with pandas.replace() without using regex ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) rather as `replace`, because  faster, then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `3` and cast to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['col'] = df.col.map({'Mr': 0, 'Mrs': 1, 'Miss': 2}).fillna(3).astype(int)

print (df)
   col
0    0
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    3
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
d = {'Mr': 0, 'Mrs': 1, 'Miss': 2}
df['col'] = np.where(df.col.isin(d.keys()), df.col.map(d), 3).astype(int)
print (df)
   col
0    0
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    3
```

Solution with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
d = {'Mr': 0, 'Mrs': 1, 'Miss': 2}
df['col'] = np.where(df.col.isin(d.keys()), df.col.replace(d), 3)
print (df)
   col
0    0
1    2
2    0
3    1
4    3
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

d = {'Mr': 0, 'Mrs': 1, 'Miss': 2}
df['col0'] = df.col.map(d).fillna(3).astype(int)
df['col1'] = np.where(df.col.isin(d.keys()), df.col.replace(d), 3)
df['col2'] = np.where(df.col.isin(d.keys()), df.col.map(d), 3).astype(int)
print (df)

In [447]: %timeit df['col0'] = df.col.map(d).fillna(3).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.93 ms per loop

In [448]: %timeit df['col1'] = np.where(df.col.isin(d.keys()), df.col.replace(d), 3)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.3 ms per loop

In [449]: %timeit df['col2'] = np.where(df.col.isin(d.keys()), df.col.map(d), 3).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.68 ms per loop

In [450]: %timeit df['col3'] = df.col.map(lambda L: d.get(L, 3))
10 loops, best of 3: 36.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Alternatively (I haven't timed it) - `df.col.map(lambda L: d.get(L, 3))`

Comment: phuuu, it is very slow, I get `In [4]: %timeit df['col3'] = df.col.map(lambda L: d.get(L, 3))` with 
`10 loops, best of 3: 36.2 ms per loop`

Comment: Ouch - not quite what I expected... what about `df.col.apply(d.get, args=(3,))`?

Comment: a bit better `In [6]: %timeit df['col3'] = df.col.apply(d.get, args=(3,))`
`10 loops, best of 3: 25.7 ms per loop`

Answer (score 12):

To add on the answer by @jezrael: The most straight forward solution is to use a *defaultdict* instead of *dict*. This is especially useful when you want missing values not to be replaced with your default value.

```
from collections import defaultdict
df['col'] = df['col'].map(defaultdict(lambda: 3, {'Mr':0, 'Mrs':1, 'Miss':2}), na_action='ignore')
```

The first argument of *defaultdict* is a function that return the default value.

Comment: Would be much more readable if the defaultdict was an object itself.